# Can't access tomcat web page from lan

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webserver, tomcat7, lan

I installed a tomcat7 server on a ubuntu 12.04 box. I simply used "apt-get install tomcat7". I did not install apache2. I can access the default page from localhost:8080, 127.0.0.1:8080, and 192.168.1.201:8080, where the latter is the IP address from my LAN. my end goal is to be able to access the web server from outside the LAN with port forwarding. For now, however, I can't even access it inside the LAN.

Problem:
I can't access the web page from any other computer (windows 7, iPad) on the same LAN! I 
get the "connection has timed out" error from the browser.

**Question:** Can I run tomcat on it's own without installing Apache2 first? This is the current setup and I can access pages hosted on tomcat on the same server, but not over the LAN.

Other information:

- I can ping the ubuntu computer from other machines
- The ubuntu firewall is disabled (checked via the firewall GUI interface).
- I also tried "sudo ufw disable"
- I tried: "sudo service iptables stop" and got the message: "iptables: unrecognized service"
- I also tried disabling the appArmor firewall:

sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor stop

sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor teardown

sudo update-rc.d -f apparmor remove

- I set the router firewall policy to minimum: inbound: accept all; outbount: accept all.
- All computers (including ubuntu server) are connected to LAN via wireless
- The ubuntu server IP address is static, not DHCP
- I checked the SELinux folder and it's empty. I removed it.

Thank you for your help,

Omar

**EDIT:**
I can connect from within the LAN using ssh (I installed OpenSSH on ubuntu).

Comment: can you ping to the tomcat server IP from other machines,telnet to port 8080  ?, are they all in a same network ? are you using proxy server to access those pages ?

Comment: Also if it is installed properly, check whether it is running on the port 8080, or any other port.

Comment: All the computers are on the same network with the same subnet mask. They can ping each other just fine. I didn't install any proxy servers. I don't think ubuntu installs a proxy server on its own, either. Tomcat7 is running on port 8080; I checked server.xml. When I changed it to other ports (e.g., 5007), I can see the page on the new port as before, but only from the same ubuntu computer. In server.xml, tomcat7 is not bound to any IP address. Please note that I didn't install APACHE2. Do I need to? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER**:

I found the solution to this problem. It turned out there was a firewall active that was blocking the port. The firewall is called "firestarter". Not sure how this was installed, but it can be downloaded from the ubuntu software center. The default inboud policy blocks all ports except for SSH (22). I opened port 8080 and everything worked just fine. The other firewalls (ufw and SELinux) were disabled.

Thank you all again for your help.

Omar

Comment: How did you open block port 8080. I'm facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure all of the IP addresses are topologically correct, then ping to the your apache server system, If all this succeeds your network is fine.

Now the question are you using the Ubuntu Server edition? if this is the case i believe you can setup apache out of the box.

In case of the Desktop edition you could install it using command line or just install something like XAMP from apache friends.

Make sure your apache Server is started

If you do not already have Apache installed, you can do so now by issuing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

This is all that is necessary to have a working web server.

Comment: I can ping and SSH from other computers to the UBUNTU computer. But still, can't connect to tomcat7 web server. I don't have APACHE2 installed. Can I host the server on tomcat7 only? Do I need apache2 first? Thank you.

Comment: As you said, if everything is ok, then possibly there is a problem with your tomcat configurations. Plz try this, in your tomcat/conf folder open server.xml file.
Try changing resolveHosts="false" to resolveHosts="true", may work. Also again check if the port 8080 can be accessed, no firewall issues.

Answer (score -1):

I think, "apt-get install tomcat7" doesnt works in Ubuntu. You have to manually download the TAR file & then you can install it with the scripts. Please check whether it is properly installed or not. it should show a Apache Tomcat Homepage @ localhost:8080

Also if it is installed properly, check whether it is running on the port 8080, or any other port.

If everything is fine, then disable the firewall of the Server, where you have installed the Tomcat. check for the server IP.

Now from other machine, access that server using `http://server_ip:port`

This should work fine. No issues should be there.

The other thing, you have metioned in your question, `UBUNTU BOX`. May be this issue arises due to UBUNTU BOX. If possible, make a clean install of Ubuntu.

Comment: I think the tomcat is installed properly. I can connect to the default page via localhost:8080, 127.0.0.1:8080, and via 192.168.1.201:8080. I also had a dynamic web application with JSP, servlets, and MySQL connections and it all worked fine, but was only able to connect from server. I installed ubuntu myself (wasn't pre-installed).